# SQL Loader load data into multiple tables with single Control file

Tags: sql-loader

I have a file with Amount Column. But Some rows in the column contains Characters. I want to load the correct amount columns in one table and Incorrect amount columns into another table.

I am using the below format to fetch the correct amount columns into Table 1.

`to_number(:amt/100)`

Into Table 2 i am not specifying any format, i am directly mentioning it as CHAR.

But both the tables are getting generated with correct amount values. (Both table 1 and 2 are using the format `to_number(:amt/100)`

```
INTO TABLE Tbl1
WHEN (01) <> 'TRAILER'
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
 amt                      POSITION(1:12)              char(12)
)


INTO TABLE tbl2
WHEN (01) <> 'TRAILER'
TRAILING NULLCOLS

(
 amt                      POSITION(1:12)            "to_number(:amt/100)",
)
```

Comment: Please show some actual data examples so we know what we are dealing with.

Answer (score 0):

You have to differentiate between tables based on the amount value condition. So, your `WHEN` condition should be like `WHEN (01) <> 'TRAILER' AND (1:12) = 'SOME_CONDITION'`.

In your case, i don't know if there is a way for conditioning column value based on its format, like REGEXP_LIKE, IS_NUMERIC, for SQL* Loader. You should look for these kinds of workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

You may be better off loading into a staging table where the column is a varchar2 so all rows will load, then process from there with a PL/SQL program.

If you show us the actual data in the column, perhaps there's a way to fix it on the way in.